# Convert SVG/CSS to SVG/SMIL

Tags: css, svg, smil

I have this spinner:

http://codepen.io/FezVrasta/pen/pJXovM

I’d like to convert it to SMIL… I have never used it so this is my first attempt and logically it doesn’t work:

```
<svg width="65px" height="65px" viewBox="0 0 66 66" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <animateTransform attributeName="transform" type="rotate" values="0;270" begin="0s" dur="1.4s" fill="freeze" repeatCount="indefinite"/>
  <circle class="path" fill="none" stroke-width="6" stroke-linecap="round" cx="33" cy="33" r="30">
    <animateTransform attributeName="transform" type="stroke-dashoffset" values="187;46.75;187" begin="0s" dur="1.4s" fill="freeze" repeatCount="indefinite"/>
    <animateTransform attributeName="transform" type="stroke" values="#4285F4;#DE3E35;#F7C223;#1B9A59;#4285F4" begin="0s" dur="5.6s" fill="freeze" repeatCount="indefinite"/>
    <animateTransform attributeName="transform" type="rotate" values="0;135;450" begin="0s" dur="1.4s" fill="freeze" repeatCount="indefinite"/>
  </circle>
</svg>
```

What am I doing wrong?

PS:
second attempt, still not working, the circle is colored but it doesn't rotate correctly:

```
<svg class="material-spinner" width="65px" height="65px" viewBox="0 0 66 66" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <animateTransform attributeName="transform" type="rotate" values="0;270" begin="0s" dur="1.4s" fill="freeze" repeatCount="indefinite"/>
  <circle class="path" fill="none" stroke-width="6" stroke-linecap="round" cx="33" cy="33" r="30">
    <animate attributeName="stroke-dashoffset" values="187;46.75;187" begin="0s" dur="1.4s" fill="freeze" repeatCount="indefinite"/>
    <animate attributeName="stroke" values="#4285F4;#DE3E35;#F7C223;#1B9A59;#4285F4" begin="0s" dur="5.6s" fill="freeze" repeatCount="indefinite"/>
    <animateTransform attributeName="transform" type="rotate" values="0;135;450" begin="0s" dur="1.4s" fill="freeze" repeatCount="indefinite"/>
  </circle>
</svg>
```

Edit:

Fixed! Here is the final result: [codepen](http://codepen.io/FezVrasta/pen/oXrgdR?editors=100)

Comment: animateTransform animates transforms, animate animates other things like stroke, stroke-dashoffset etc. Only Firefox supports transforms on `<svg>` elements currently.

Comment: Thanks but even using `animate` instead of `animateTransform` the thing doesn't work :(

Comment: I wonder who voted to close because the q is "too broad"... here there is a **specific** solution.

Comment: As I said in my first comment animateTransform works on transform attributes. animate works on non-transform attributes.